# Integral over circle

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Consider the following integral:

$\displaystyle \int_{|z-3i|=1} \frac{e^{z^2+z}}{z} dz$.

Why is my approach wrong?

Set $f(z)=e^{z^2+z}$, then from the Cauchy integral formula for circles, we have:

$\displaystyle f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z-3i|=1} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz$.

So we have: $\displaystyle \int_{|z-3i|=1} \frac{e^{z^2+z}}{z} dz = 2 \pi i$.

Where is the mistake?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $0$ is outside your circle $|z-3i|=1$, not inside.

Comment: I see, so the integral is zero using the Cauchy integral theorem.